# How do you find the time complexity in terms of theta for the following question?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

[Question from my university exam, 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD7fs.png)

The above link has the question I'm referring to in detail(It's an image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, First Let's assume for loop will execute k times then see the value of j in kth instruction is **j = 2(1) + 2(2) + 2(3) + ....... + 2(k)
j = k^2 + k**
but you know **j <= n** so solve it you get **k <= (-1 + root( 1 + 4n )) /2**

so you can same it has time complexity of **O(root(n))**

Comment: Thanks, this helps. How do I close this thread?

Comment: @CherylParker you need 250 reputations to close the thread

Answer (score 0):

You can write an equation to find the number of loop iteration:

```
2 * 1 + 2 * 2 + ... + 2 * k = n
```

`k` means the number of iteration for the loop up to `j <= n`.
Hence,

```
2 (1 + 2 +... +k) = n => 2 (k(k+1)/2) = n 
=> k(k+1) = n => k = Theta(sqrt(n))
```

Therefore, as th other operation is assumed to be in `Theta(1)`, total time complexity of the algorithm is in `Theta(sqrt(n))`.